# What package should I load to use refsegment?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

I am using this thesis template: https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/

I want to print a reference list for each chapter. When I insert the following command I get a lot of errors.

The command I want:

```
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,title=first bib]
```

attempts:
1) I tried pasting this command at the end of the chapter
2) I tried pasting it after the "include\chapter" command in the main file

nothing worked

the errors I get:
for bibtex:

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
The top-level auxiliary file: thesis.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file thesis.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file thesis.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file thesis.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

for latex:
I get "Undefined control sequence"

I am not inserting anything related to bibliography in the preamble, I thought this could be the problem?

I am using this in the main file:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % Use for unsorted references  
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % use this to have URLs listed in References
\cleardoublepage
\bibliography{References/references} % Path to your References.bib file
```

Comment: The upper part is completely incompatible with the lower part of your question. For the upper, you need package `biblatex`.

Comment: A thesis template leads to confusion. *shocked*

Comment: @Johannes_B How do I make them compatible? I need to use the IEEE style and I need to print the references for each chapter. 
I just tried to use
 '\usepackage{biblatex}' 
and 
'\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}' in the preamble and I still can't get the document to compile. Insight appreciated.

Comment: First you have to decide between using `biblatex` and an IEEE compatible style, *or* using the older BibTeX/natbib system along with a package for split bibliographies.

Comment: There must be a solution to use IEEE and print the reference list for each chapter. Are you sure there isn't? @Johannes_B

Comment: There is, and you can choose two ways. Either with biblatex, or with classic bibtex/natbib.

Comment: @Johannes_B I added this line to the preamble `\usepackage[style=ieee]{bibla­tex}`, this line to the chapter `\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,title=first bib]` and this line to the main file `\bibliography{References/references} `. I still have an error. What am i doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the LaTeX wikibook but using IEEE.

[image: sadbeeBiblatexIeee]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,refsection=section]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Aster}
\cite{ctan,sigfridsson} and some text
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\section{Begonia}
\cite{aristotle:physics,markey}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\section{Cichorium}
\cite{westfahl:space,baez/online}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}|
```

You need to run biber as defined by the `backend`.

Comment: It does not work. Do you know why? 
I added `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,refsection=section]{biblatex}`  and `\addbibresource{References/references.bib}` to my preamble file. and `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]` to my chapter file. I did not add anything to the main file. I tried also to remove the  `\addbibresource{References/references.bib}` from the preamble file to the main file, still no luck. @Johannes_B

Comment: You need to test the example as is first. Get this to work, then aply to your real example. Your question would have been more suited for a usual forum, not a Question/Answer site.